Android does not change the language of string resources in a Fragment
I have an app with string resources for German and English. I defined a separate Fragment for changing the language that you can see here
public class FR_Options extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {



    /*
    String specifying the language of the App
     */

    public static final String LANGUAGE_GERMAN = "German";
    public static final String LANGUAGE_ENGLISH = "English";
    //Set the default language to GERMAN
    public static String currentLanguageOfTheApp = LANGUAGE_ENGLISH;

    public FR_Options() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static FR_Options newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FR_Options fragment = new FR_Options();

        return fragment;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }


    private FragmentOptionsBinding binding;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = FragmentOptionsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        binding.imageButtonGermany.setOnClickListener(this);
        binding.imageButtonUK.setOnClickListener(this);
        if(currentLanguageOfTheApp.equals(LANGUAGE_ENGLISH)) {
            binding.textViewCurrentLanguageValue.setText(LANGUAGE_ENGLISH);
            binding.imageButtonGermany.setAlpha(0.5f);
            binding.imageButtonUK.setAlpha(1.0f);
        }
        if(currentLanguageOfTheApp.equals(LANGUAGE_GERMAN)) {
            binding.textViewCurrentLanguageValue.setText(LANGUAGE_GERMAN);
            binding.imageButtonGermany.setAlpha(1.0f);
            binding.imageButtonUK.setAlpha(0.5f);
        }

    }


    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if(view.getId() == R.id.imageButtonGermany) {

             /*
            Set the language to "German" for other fragments and database queries
             */

            this.currentLanguageOfTheApp = LANGUAGE_GERMAN;


            /*
            Set the language to "German" for the XML-layout files
             */



            Locale locale;
            locale = new Locale("de", "DE");

            Configuration config = new Configuration(getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration());
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            config.setLocale(locale);
            getActivity().recreate();

            getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                    getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());






        }

        if(view.getId() == R.id.imageButtonUK) {

            /*
            Set the language to "English" for other fragments and database queries
             */

            this.currentLanguageOfTheApp = LANGUAGE_ENGLISH;


            /*
            Set the language to "English" for the XML-layout files
             */


            Locale locale;
            locale = new Locale("en", "EN");

            Configuration config = new Configuration(getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration());
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            config.setLocale(locale);
            getActivity().recreate();

            getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                    getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());


        }


    }


}

Now when I navigate to a Test fragment whose Java file looks like this
public class Test extends Fragment  {



    int widthDisplay;
    int heightDisplay;


    private FragmentTestBinding binding;

    private ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
    ConstraintSet constraintSet ;




    private boolean fragmentViewHasBeenCreated = false;


    int helpUpdateCounterProgressBar = 0;//Just for testing

    boolean animationIsWindBladRotating = false;



    private boolean sunIsShiningForImagewViews = false;

    private boolean helpSolarGameRectangleCorrectlyCaughtPreviously = false;

    public Test() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentTestBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getActivity().getWindowManager();
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        widthDisplay = size.x;
        heightDisplay = size.y;

        //Test to set the string resources programmatically
        String goalText = getString(R.string.goal);
        String timeText = getString(R.string.time);
        binding.textViewGoal.setText(goalText);
        binding.textView3.setText(timeText);


        container.getContext();
        constraintLayout= binding.constraintLayout;


        fragmentViewHasBeenCreated = true;
        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        constraintLayout = binding.constraintLayout;
        constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
        return binding.getRoot();



    }//end onCreateView


    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();

        // Reset your variable to false
        fragmentViewHasBeenCreated = false;

    }
}

with the corrsponding xml layout file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_Goal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/goal"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/time"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView_Goal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView_Goal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_Goal" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

The languages of the string resources android:text="@string/time" and android:text="@string/goal" never change and always remain English which is the default language.
In the folder values/string/strings.xml there are the two entries
"    <string name="goal">Goal</string>
    <string name="time">Time</string>"

while in the folder values/string/strings.mxl (de-rDE) there are the two entries "
    <string name="goal">Ziel</string> 
<string name="time">Zeit</string>"

still the laguage is not changes in the Test class no matter what I do in the FR_Options fragment class.
Update: I found out that when changing the language in the FR_Options class and I navigate back to my FR_Menu class which looks like this
public class FR_Menu extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    private FragmentMenuBinding binding;



    public FR_Menu() {

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentMenuBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        binding.buttonGame.setOnClickListener(this);
        binding.buttonOptions.setOnClickListener(this);
        binding.buttonHighscores.setOnClickListener(this);
        binding.buttonFacts.setOnClickListener(this);
        binding.buttonExit.setOnClickListener(this);
        binding.buttonTest.setOnClickListener(this);

        Log.e("LogTag_Menu", "Method onCreateView - this: " + this);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if(view.getId() == R.id.button_game) {
            Navigation.findNavController(getView()).navigate(FR_MenuDirections.actionFRMenuToFRGame());
        }

        if(view.getId() == R.id.button_highscores) {
            Navigation.findNavController(getView()).navigate(FR_MenuDirections.actionFRMenuToFRHighScores());
        }

        if(view.getId() == R.id.button_facts) {
            //Navigation.findNavController(getView()).navigate(FR_MenuDirections.actionFRMenuToFRInterestingFacts());
            Navigation.findNavController(getView()).navigate(FR_MenuDirections.actionFRMenuToFRRVLevelSelectionMenu());
        }

        if(view.getId() == R.id.button_options) {
            Navigation.findNavController(getView()).navigate(FR_MenuDirections.actionFRMenuToFROptions());
        }

        if(view.getId() == R.id.button_test) {
            Navigation.findNavController(getView()).navigate(FR_MenuDirections.actionFRMenuToTest());
        }


        if(view.getId() == R.id.button_exit) {
            getActivity().finishAndRemoveTask();
        }

    }
}

the language of the string resources are correctly changed. However, when navigating from the FR_Menu class to another class, the language of the string resources changes back to the default (English) again. Why is this happening?
Reminder: Does anybody have an idea as to why this is happening and how to solve this problem?

Why are you handling the language change on the fragment itself and not delegating it to the activity that is hosting the fragment?

@tomerpacific: Thanks tomer for your comment. What do you mean by "delegating it to the activity that is hosting the fragment"? As far as I see it, I am doing that by using the code             getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,                     getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics()); but unfortunately this does not change the language in other fragments.

@tomerpacific: any comments to my last comment? I'll highly appreciate any further comment from you

You need a context wrapper to wrap the new language in the new configuration when the activity is recreated

@Zain: Thanks for your comment. What do you actually mean by "context wrapper" and how can I use it when the activity is recreated? Maybe you can give me an example of how it could look like in my code?

@VanessaF, why not use the officially recommended per-app language api instead?  It's easier and more straightforward to implement. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages#java

@Itp: Thanks for your comment. How can I use this approach to change the language?

currentLanguageOfTheApp is a local variable to FR_Options; so it's not globally saved in persistent storage.
You need to save it persistently typically in SharedPrefs or DataStore, so when the activity is recreated you can get last saved language by the user.
With SharedPreference, something like
private static final String LANGUAGE = "LANGUAGE";
private static final String SHARED_PREFS_NAME= "SHARED_PREFS_NAME";

private static String getLanguage(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return prefs.getString(LANGUAGE, "en");
}

private static String setLanguage(Context context, String language) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(LANGUAGE, language);
    editor.apply();
}   

And when changing the language by the user, set that to the SharedPrefs, and restart the activity:
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    
    if(view.getId() == R.id.imageButtonGermany) {
        setLanguage(requireContext(), "de");        
    }

    if(view.getId() == R.id.imageButtonUK) {
        setLanguage(requireContext(), "en");    
    }

    // restart the activity
    requireActivity().finish();
    requireActivity().startActivity(new Intent(requireActivity(), MainActivity.class));

}

So far this will just save the new languange in a persistent storage, and restarted the activity, but to apply the new language when the activity is recreated, the new baseContext needs to map the string file of the new language instead of the default language String file. So, you need a context wrapper to wrap the new language in the new configuration of the baseContext when the activity is recreated.
In code, you'd create the below ContextWrapper:
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Build;

import java.util.Locale;

public class LanguageContextWrapper extends ContextWrapper {

    public LanguageContextWrapper(Context base) {
        super(base);
    }

    public static ContextWrapper wrap(Context context, String language) {
        Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        Locale sysLocale;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            sysLocale = getSystemLocale(config);
        } else {
            sysLocale = getSystemLocaleLegacy(config);
        }
        if (!language.isEmpty() && !sysLocale.getLanguage().equals(language)) {
            Locale locale = new Locale(language);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                setSystemLocale(config, locale);
            } else {
                setSystemLocaleLegacy(config, locale);
            }

        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
        } else {
            context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
        return new LanguageContextWrapper(context);
    }

    public static Locale getSystemLocaleLegacy(Configuration config) {
        return config.locale;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public static Locale getSystemLocale(Configuration config) {
        return config.getLocales().get(0);
    }

    public static void setSystemLocaleLegacy(Configuration config, Locale locale) {
        config.locale = locale;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public static void setSystemLocale(Configuration config, Locale locale) {
        config.setLocale(locale);
    }
}

And use it in activity's attachBaseContext() callback:
class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        String language = getLanguage(newBase);
        super.attachBaseContext(LanguageContextWrapper.wrap(newBase, language));
        setLocale(getLanguage(newBase));
    }

    private void setLocale(String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Resources resources = getBaseContext().getResources();
        Configuration conf = resources.getConfiguration();
        conf.setLocale(locale);
        resources.updateConfiguration(conf, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
    }

// ........ reset of your activity
    
}


Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I have problems understanding it as I don't know where to add this code. For example the get and setLanguage methods, shall they be in the FR_Options fragment or in the Main Activity fragment?

Is there not an easier way of doing this? In another app I just do it as in this app. There is no difference at all (I in fact copied and pasted the code) and there everything works fine without all this Shared Preferences and Wrapper approaches that you are suggesting. But I have not figured out why it is not working in this app. Maybe can you think of another approach how to do this without and wrapper and shared preferences?

@VanessaF How do you save the new language in the next launch of the other app? don't you use a persistent storage?

No, I don't use the shared preferences approach. It seems to introduce unecessary complexity. In my other app, the user should decide at every start which language to choose. If I wanted to have a pesistent storage, I would rather use a sql database for instance. This way it is way easier than using ContextWrappers and SharedPreferences

In your suggested code, where should be get and setLanguage methods? Is this a separate class or shall they be in the Main Activity?

It's in FR_Options fragment as it's just called from there

Thanks a lot Zain for your answer. Now it works and I awarded the bounty to you :-). There is a small error in the code. In the method private static String setLanguage(Context context, String language) { you don't return anything. So I had to change the method declaration to void

Just out of curiosity I would like to ask what advantages your suggested approach with the Shareed Preferences has compared to just using a simple sql database query to persistantly store the currently used language? With a sql query you would need way less code and it would have reduced complexity, especially due to the fact that no additional classes would be necessary.

Well you are right in that regard.. but SQL database mainly used to save a bunch of structured data with different fields and columns . But you just need to save a single value for language.. probably maintaining the SQL db has some effort as well

Thanks a lot for your comment. I use SQLite databases for everything as it is very easy and fast and reduces the complexity. You wrote "But you just need to save a single value for language" --> I would argue the other way round. If I just need to save a single value, why shall I use such a highly complex appraoch with the shared preferences and additional classes that just introduces unnecessary complexity and many many lines of additional code, while in SQLite you just need  2 very small get and set methods.

Under the hood SQLite has overhead of creating a database, opening and closing, not just simple like as you code it; it requires background thread to access even.. Also SharedPreference is now replaced with DataStore.. I just added SharedPrefs in this question as sample data persistence solution; but every app has its own data persistence management that is out of this question scope.. the bottom line is that you need some way to store the language persistently to be retrieved in the next app launch

Thanks for your answer and effort Zain. I have 2 follow-up questions: 1) In you suggested solution, I don't understand why you need a LanguageContextWrapper  class and what is actually done there? As stated before, in my other app there is no need for something like this. Whenenver the language is changed, it stays as it should no matter which fragment you are navigating to 2) I noticed that you use a lot of static methods (both in the LanguageContextWrapper  and in the FR_Options). I was told 1000 times that one should never use static methods as it is considered bad style

I have a further third question: 3) Is it possible to change the language without restarting the activity? So the user can just choose the language in the FR_Options class and after pressing a button for the language, the app should not navigate to another fragment

Getting a string resource value requires a context  and that context is associated to only 1 string resource that is loaded on the activity start..  when you change the language, you also need to reflect that change to the context to pick the new string resource of that language; that is what LanguageContextWrapper does .. I can't tell more about the other app as I had no idea how it works.. if you can give me a sample working light version, it would be helpful

Is it possible to change the language without restarting the activity? As far as I know, no you can't. Do you restart the activity on your other app?

Thanks for your answer and sorry for my late reply (I was on vacation). In my other app, I don't really know if the activity is restarted again. At least I stay in the same fragment such that you can change the language and stay in the same fragment. Is it possible with your approach to change the language and stay in the same fragment? Further you wrote "you also need to reflect that change to the context to pick the new string resource of that language; that is what LanguageContextWrapper" --> in my other app there is no need for this. It just changes the language and it works great

Thanks for your answers. Any comments on my last comment? I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you.

Is your other app a multi-fragment one? if yes do other fragment provide the new language resource?>>>> Is it possible with your approach to change the language and stay in the same fragment?  I don't think without manual effort, I admit I have to look thoroughly for a workaround

Thanks for your comment. My other app has one main activity and multiple fragments. I use the navGraph to navigate between them. When I change the language in the FR_Options  (whose code you can see above in my very first code posting), the language is changed for every fragment (that include string ressources). This works without problems


Just update the order of these lines in your code.

//here the activity reload its resources based on the new configuration
getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

// restart the current activity 
getActivity().recreate();
       


Thanks for your answer harsh. I tried it but it did not change anything. However, I now use the solution from Zain which works fine. Still, I highly appreciate your effort.
